Can I use wall framing as a concrete form?
I am pouring a small (30x30x3") concrete slab for a water heater. It will be poured onto the existing concrete floor of my basement. The primary reason is because the existing floor is poorly finished and uneven. I have a concrete adhesive by Quikrete that is supposed to help the new concrete bond to the old. This will be my first concrete project, but I've been reading a lot!
I also need to build a wall next to the heater to allow for seismic strapping. The existing heater is simply standing there, on a rusted metal stand, otherwise unsupported :)
My answer is to build a small utility closet around both the water heater and a nearby furnace. I would not finish the inside of the closet, just leave the beams accessible to support the water heater and plumbing.
Incomplete example:

The "traditional" method is to pour the slab, remove the forms, then build the wall. I'd have to attach the forms to the concrete floor somehow before doing the pour. And I'd need to attach the bottom plates to the floor, which worries me since the existing concrete is very thin, old, and shoddy.
It occurred to me that I could build the wall first (doubling up on the bottom plate) and then just pour in the concrete.
Possible benefits:

The wall would keep the "forms" (bottom plates) pressed up against the existing floor while the concrete was being poured.
It would save the work of removing forms and finishing the edges.
I could put long bolts through the bottom plates, then pour the concrete around the bolts, to anchor the walls to the concrete.

Is this a bad idea? What are your thoughts?

The plan is fine (use pt for ground contact), but it’s not clear if you’ve considered moving the water heater to a nearby wall and skipping the ‘build a closet’ experience. Plus, I’m pretty sure the two-sided closet could be a single wall.

Perhaps reduce even more to a couple of Lally columns...

Well, for one thing, at least based on your sketch it looks like the bottom plates are shorter than your slab, so you'd need some forms on top of the bottom plate, at a minimum.

@Huesmann, yeah, figured I'd double-up on the bottom plates. I would have to put a temporary form board on one side in the direction of the furnace...

Thanks, @Aloysius :) There is no nearby wall. I could move the heater (I'm repiping anyway), but I figured it would go well next to the existing free-standing furnace (which I can't move)...

Thanks, @Ecnerwal, good thought :)
